# Getting a syntax error when displaying a matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix, syntax-error

here is the code:

```
#STARTING MESSAGE

print('Any *num* is a numerator, and any *den* is a denominator. *num1* is for the first fraction, and *num2* is for the second fraction. Same thing with the denominators. Please enter num1, saying *num1 = x* with the num1 =. THIS ONLY WORKS WITH NUMBERS 1 THROUGH 100!')

#DEN1

num1 = 3
if num1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 02, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]:
    print(now enter den1)



den1 = 34
if den1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 02, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]:
    print(now enter num2)

#SEC == 2

num2 = 4
if num2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 02, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]:
    print(now enter den2)



den2 = 33
if den2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 02, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]:
    print(CALCULATING...)

#CALCULATING CODE

den1*num2 = secondFrac

den2*num1 = firstFrac

if firstFrac > secondFrac:
    print('The first fraction is greater then the second fraction! *First_Fraction > Second_Fraction!*')



if firstFrac < secondFrac:
    print('The second fraction is greater then the first fraction! *First_Fraction < Second_Fraction!*')
```

I am getting a syntax error with the matrixes, just saying "Syntax Error: Invalid Syntax"

Comment: Typo: `02` → `92`. There are other issues as well.

Comment: @ForceBru, that did not help, but thanks anyways

Comment: I can actually use 'True' instead of a matrix, so thank you for all of your help.